# Why this ASM instructions load 10?

Tags: java, java-bytecode-asm

I was testing with ASM framework, and I barely can't understand why this fragment of code produce the int value `10`.
For more details: the method returns an int and I printed the int back.

```java
// This is the complete ASM visit of this method
// ...
MethodVisitor mv = cw.visitMethod(Opcodes.ACC_PUBLIC, method.getName(), Type.getMethodDescriptor(method), null, null);
mv.visitCode();
mv.visitIntInsn(Opcodes.BIPUSH, 0);

mv.visitIntInsn(Opcodes.BIPUSH , 0);
mv.visitIntInsn(Opcodes.ISTORE, 2);

mv.visitIntInsn(Opcodes.ILOAD, 1);
mv.visitInsn(Opcodes.IRETURN);

mv.visitMaxs(0, 0);
mv.visitEnd();
// ...
```

The decompiler show even some weird code.
**Decompiler output**:

```
//
// Source code recreated from a .class file by IntelliJ IDEA
// (powered by Fernflower decompiler)
//

public class HelloWorld implements Add {
    public HelloWorld() {
    }

    public int add(int var1, int var2) {
        boolean var3 = false;
        return var1;
    }
}
```

1. Why does the function returns `10` ? Is it a bug ? Does this invoke a sort of "undefined behaviour", because variables are loaded into "self" because pushed back?
2. How does JVM handle the variables and how to allocate it, is it stack based ? If so, then the `aload` will just push duplicate value of data

```
stack before aload: var1 var2 var3
stack after aload_1: var1 var2 var3 var1
```

Or am I totally wrong? It looks like a bit overworks instead of using registries.

Comment: I don’t see a `10` anywhere in your code, neither the generator nor the decompiled code. Your method returns the first argument, in the decompiled code the parameter is labeled as `var1`.

Comment: That's why I don't understand where the `10` comes.
edit: I was testing with dummy values because i thought i didn't change anything  and actually the call was done with `System.out.println(inst.add(10, 20))` !

Comment: As said, this code returns the first argument, so if the first argument is ten, it will return ten. When you look at your invocation `inst.add(10, 20)`, it should be obvious where the ten is coming from.

Comment: This exactly confirms what I wrote in my answer: _"So if the method returns 10, it means that you must have called the method with a var1 value of 10 (...)"_ Only I explained in much more detail in order for you to understand better. So please accept the answer in order to close this question. Much appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Who wrote that byte code? What is it supposed to do? What it actually does is:

- push `(byte) 0` onto operand stack as an integer
- push `(byte) 0` onto operand stack one more time
- pop top-most `0` from stack and store as integer in local variable table, slot #2
- load integer from local variable table slot #1 (note: different slot than before) onto the stack
- return top-most stack element as method result

You also need to know that in the local variable table

- #0 is `this` for the called method, i.e. a reference to the `HelloWorld` instance,
- #1 is the first method parameter `var1`,
- #2 is the second method parameter `var2`.

So if the method returns 10, it means that you must have called the method with a `var1` value of 10 because you return the content of slot #1 unchanged. There is no clue that you add anything here like the method name implies. What it does instead is push 2x `0` onto the stack, but only using one of them, overwriting `var2` for whatever reason before returning `var1`, as I said. The decompiler then tries to make sense of it, doing a pretty good job.

---

**Update:** If you want to implement this

```java
public int add(int var1, int var2) {
  return var1 + var2;
}
```

then your byte code ought to be like this:

```
ILOAD 1
ILOAD 2
IADD
IRETURN
```